# Get Javascript Object Property Name

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to know if are there any way to get field name or property name dynamically inside my jquery.grep function

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var names = [];
var object = {
    name: "Joe",
    age: 20,
    email: "joe@hotmail.com"
};
names.push(object);
object = {
    name: "Mike",
    age: 50,
    email: "mikoooe@hotmail.com"
};
names.push(object);
object = {
    name: "Joe",
    age: 45,
    email: "mikezz@hotmail.com"
};
names.push(object);

var found_names = $.grep(names, function(v,y) {
    return v.name === "Mike" && v.age <= 50;
});

$(document).ready(function(){

console.log(found_names);
});

</script>
```

what i get actually with this code are name and age values according a condition but what about if i wanted to get the key names i.e. name, age, email. Is that possible on my function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you used grep you basically created a new array with the objects that has a name "Mike" and are below 50 or equal to 50. 
In your case you can loop through your new array and print the key and value.

```
found_names.forEach(function (obj) {
   console.log('Name: ' + obj.name);
   console.log('Age: ' + obj.age);
   console.log('Email: ' + obj.email);
});
```

If you want the index(key) you can also do

```
found_names.forEach(function (obj, index) {
       console.log('Index: ' + index);
       console.log('Name: ' + obj.name);
       console.log('Age: ' + obj.age);
       console.log('Email: ' + obj.email);
});
```

> Edit 2 -

If you have a dynamic object where you don't know the keys you can use what Thiago suggested and tweaking it a bit. The example below would loop through every object then would go through its data.

```
found_names.forEach(function (obj) {
    for(key in obj){
        console.log(key + ': ' + obj[key]);
    }
});
```

Another example would be using an array like object where you loop through an object like you are looping in an array.

```
found_names.forEach(function (obj, index, array) {
    array.forEach(function(data){
        // data would be the current index 
        console.log(array[data]);
    });
});
```

[Here is an example on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/40xuxuvj/)

[Source for forEach Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Comment: Joseph, is it possible to get the keys dynamically with no need to name it one by one as your example above? Maybe a new function without jquery grep. Your information about grep is creating a new array is really useful.

Comment: yes you can, you can use what thiago suggested using for loop. let me give you an example @CabezzCabezz

Comment: I have a list of object in an array, for that reason the Thiago's sample doesn't work for me, or at least i just dont know how to get key from my list objects.

Comment: @CabezzCabezz the reason thiago's example might not work is because you might have a list of objects while his method only works for looping through 1 object. I've also updated my answer giving you a better understanding

Comment: Yes I'm testing, but on the first example it works really well and on the 2th one, i just get an error, so i'm trying to identify where is it.

Comment: Joseph, the first example works really fine. Thank you so much, i just don't know why the 2th sample doesn't work because sounds interesting.

Comment: @CabezzCabezz might be a syntax error from my end but the one on JSFiddle is probably the one you were looking for. I just noticed couple of errors.. had couple of closing brackets missing lol

Answer (score 2):

You can loop through the properties of an object by doing this-

```
var myObj = { name: "John", age: 28 }

for (var key in myObj) {
    console.log("key: " + key);
    console.log("value: " + myObj[key]);
}

//prints
key: name
value: John
key: age
value: 28
```

Comment: Can i do it from my grep function? By the way, your example can't be adapted on my names object because when y try to get the key i get the index and when i try to get the value, i just get undefined value.

Comment: Thiago, I don't know whats going on, when i try the demo on chrome or firefox, everything works ok, but on ie8 it just don't work. Do you suggest me any solution?